# Factory pattern when the abstract product is generic class

Tags: java, generics, graph, factory-pattern

the first part of my project is to construct an hypergraph

This is a quickly-drew UML diagram [image]

Vertex class

```
public abstract class Vertex <T>{

    int vertexId ;
    T vertexValue ;
    public  abstract  T computeVertexValue();
}
```

Imagevertex Class

```
public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, Instance>>{


    public ImageVertex(int id ) {
        this.vertexId=id;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Instance> computeVertexValue(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

AbstractVertexFactory

```
public abstract class AbstractVertexFactory {

    public abstract  Vertex createVertex(int id);

    public  Vertex produceVertex(int id) {

        Vertex vertex = createVertex(id);
        vertex.computeVertexValue();
        return vertex;
    }
}
```

ImageFactory class

```
public class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory {

    @Override
    public Vertex createVertex(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ImageVertex(id);
    }
}
```

Simulator

```
public class ImageFactorySimulator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        AbstractVertexFactory imFactory= new ImageFactory();

        ImageVertex im = (ImageVertex) imFactory.createVertex(0);

    }

}
```

the use of cast in the simulator is boared 
How can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
public abstract class AbstractVertexFactory <T extends Vertex> {
    public abstract  T createVertex(int id);
}
```

And

```
public class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory<ImageVertex> {

    @Override
    public ImageVertex createVertex(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ImageVertex(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
abstract class AbstractVertexFactory<T extends Vertex> {
    public abstract Vertex createVertex(int id);
}

class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory<ImageVertex> {
    @Override
    public ImageVertex createVertex(int id) {
        return new ImageVertex(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer is:

```
public abstract class Vertex <T>{

    int vertexId ;
    T vertexValue ;
    public  abstract  T computeVertexValue();
}
public class ImageVertex extends Vertex<Map<String, Object>>{


    public ImageVertex(int id ) {
        this.vertexId=id;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> computeVertexValue(){
        return null;
    }
}
public abstract class AbstractVertexFactory<T extends Vertex> {

    public abstract  T createVertex(int id);

    public  T produceVertex(int id) {

        T vertex = createVertex(id);
        vertex.computeVertexValue();
        return vertex;
    }
}

public class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory<ImageVertex> {

    @Override
    public ImageVertex createVertex(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ImageVertex(id);
    }
}

public class ImageFactorySimulator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void ttt(String[] args) {


        ImageFactory imFactory= new ImageFactory();

        ImageVertex im = imFactory.createVertex(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public class ImageFactory extends AbstractVertexFactory {

    @Override
    public Vertex createVertex(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return createImageVertex(id);
    }

    public ImageVertex createImageVertex(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ImageVertex(id);
    }
}
```

AND

```
public class ImageFactorySimulator {

    /**
         * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        AbstractVertexFactory imFactory= new ImageFactory();

        ImageVertex im = imFactory.createImageVertex(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this will compile, but no longer follows the abstract factory pattern.